# Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{F}[u]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, multivariate-polynomial

Is it possible to map from $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{F}[u]$ where each monomial $x^ay^b = u^{aw+b}$ for appropriate choice of $w$?

In fact this mapping $\phi(x^ay^b) = u^{aw+b}$ seems to be multiplicative $\phi(z_1)\phi(z_2) = \phi(z_1z_2)$.

Is it a ring homomorphism? What is it called in literature?

Comment: Sure. For any $g(u),h(u)\in \Bbb{F}[u]$ then $\phi(f(x,y))=f(g(u),h(u))$ is a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{F}[x,y]\to \mathbb{F}[u]$ . You can call it the evaluation map at $(g,h)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family $\{x^ny^m\ \mid\ n,m\in\mathbb N_0\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb F[x,y]$ as $\mathbb F$-vector space. Hence any choice of a family of polynomials $F_{nm}(u)\in\mathbb F[u]$ will naturally extend to a $\mathbb F$-linear map $F\colon\mathbb F[x,y]\to\mathbb F[u]$. If additionally

$$F((x^{n_1}y^{m_1})(x^{n_2}y^{m_2}))=F(x^{n_1}y^{m_1})F(x^{n_2}y^{m_2})$$

this map will be a ring homomorphism. You can check that this suffices by explicitely computing the product of two polynomials in $\mathbb F[x,y]$ using the $\mathbb F$-linearity of $F$.

In your case $F_{nm}(u)=u^{nw+m}$ and

\begin{align*}
F((x^{n_1}y^{m_1})(x^{n_2}y^{m_2}))
&=F(x^{n_1+n_2}y^{m_1+m_2})
\\
&=u^{(n_1+n_2)w+(m_1+_2)}
\\
&=u^{n_1w+m_1}u^{n_2w+m_2}
\\
&=F(x^{n_1}y^{m_1})F(x^{n_2}y^{m_2})\ .
\end{align*}

So $F$ is a ring homomorphism as desired. For the map *reuns* proposed you can choose

$$F_{nm}(u)=g(u)^nh(u)^m$$

and multiplicativity is straigtforward as well. For $g(u)=u^w$ and $h(u)=u$ this becomes your map again.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. Any idea how I could *undo* the mapping if the product, $nm$, is used?

Comment: @conchild What do you mean by "the product $nm$ is used"?

Comment: The map $\phi(x^{n_1}y^{n_2})$ by $u^{{n_1}w+n_2}$ is reversible if all $n_i$ bounded by $w$.

Comment: @conchild So you want to define an inverse map $\phi^{-1}$? Such a map won't exists as $\mathbb F[x,y]$ and $\mathbb F[u]$ aren't isomorphic.